# Is there a way to change a member of a const struct?

Tags: c++, constants

I want to change a member of a `const` function argument. imagine this snippet from a texture class I am working on:

```
template<>
void mySuperTexture::loadPixels<float>(uint32 _width, uint32 _height, float * _pixels, const Settings & _settings)
{
    if (_settings.pixelDataType == PixelDataType::Auto) {
       _settings.pixelDataType = PixelDataType::Float32;
       // ^ obviously this does not work on the const variable
    }
    // ...
    m_pimpl->loadPixels(_width, _height, _pixels, _settings);
}
```

I know that I could make the argument non-`const`, but that would not allow me to specify a default argument for the settings argument, or call the function with a temp variable.

I guess I could make a copy of the Settings `struct` inside the loadPixels function but I'd like to avoid that. Any other ideas?

**EDIT:**

Okay, I decided to go with the mutable keyword.- Here is why: In my scenario the Settings struct is basically only used during the construction of the texture/loading of the pixels and not stored afterwards.- Thus the `mutable` does not change anything about the constness for the user since its simply not accessible. Overloading does seem to be more of a pain in my situtation since I am implementing the loadPixels method for various types( i.e. unsigned char, short, int ...) thus just overloading would increase the amount of source code **alot**. Btw. the actuall settings get saved inside a *pimpl* object (whose loadPixel function is not templated and thus does not know anything about the type) thats why I want to work directly on the const Settings struct.

Comment: You could declare `Settings::pixelDataType` as `mutable`.

Comment: You should use `const` for non-mutable data, not to give you the ability to use temporaries. Don't circumvent the system.

Comment: a yeah the mutable keyword was what I was looking for, thanks! @Tomalak, well i am very sure that this is an exception where it makes sense!

Comment: I couldn't more strongly disagree. :(

Comment: @moka: Equally, `mutable` should not be used as a hack.  `mutable` is designed for situations where you have logical `const`-ness that nevertheless requires bitwise manipulation under the hood (examples implementing lazy evaluation, copy-on-write, etc.).

Comment: okay, I guess I will try the overloading then.- Anyways right now I feel that it just creates more source code in my situation which is also a potential error source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Do a `const_cast <> ()`
2. Mark the member as `mutable`

But, as you want to update const-y and non-consty things, I guess you want to overload the function with a non-const version:

```
template<>
void mySuperTexture::loadPixels<float>(uint32 _width, uint32 _height, float * _pixels, Settings & _settings)
```

and then put common code into another function.

Comment: Perhaps mutable should come first, as it's the less evil.

Comment: Perhaps recommendation about overloading should come alone, w/o any evils

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear to me why you should be modifying the settings parameter.

```
int pixelDataType = _settings.pixelDataType;
if (pixelDataType == PixelDataType::Auto) {
   pixelDataType = PixelDataType::Float32;
}
```

Other suggestions don't seem sound. Casting constness away in order to modify a const object leads to undefined behavior. Also it is not a good idea to make perfectly ordinary data members mutable, as it would make the const keyword lose much of its value.

If you want to avoid a copy but store a reference/pointer to the Settings, this is not a good idea, because the lifetime of the Settings object can easily be shorter than the texture object. Making a copy would give most robust code here.

As an alternative you could get rid of `PixelDataType::Auto` altogether, and have `Settings` initialize this member to `Float32` itself (e.g. by default).

Answer (score 0):

If you really know what sou're doing, you could cast the constness away (see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ ), but using const cast is almost always a sign of a bad design.